# Replacements for Dataset / Out of Memory

Tags: c#, .net, database, memory, dataset

Is there any replacement to Dataset, so Data is saved to the disk, rather than stored in memory? I have to populate a dataset with an enormous amount of data, which can cause Out Of Memory exceptions. There is nothing I can do to reduce the amount of data as it’s driven by user requirements.

Comment: You need to hold the whole dataset in memory? really?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve by doing this?

Comment: Is your dataset loading from a database?

Comment: Lateral thinking: Is loading the whole dataset really necessary?

Answer (score 1):

I would check if it would be possible to use a `DataReader` instead, as you then would process the records as they arrive from the database instead of first storing everything in memory.

Comment: I'm not loading all the data just a user specified subset of it. The data is being used to populate a pivot table, which needs all the records to calculate the totals.

Comment: @Tim: With "everything" I of course meant the data that you actually load. If you really need all that data all at once, then you could use a `DataReader` to read it into objects that are specifically made for storing only that data, which would be more lightweight than a `DataTable`.